# Question about sum of measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This could be very easy, but i don't get it.

> I have to state conditions for which, given a measurable extended real function $f$ on $X$ and two positive measure $m_1$, $m_2$ on the same sigma algebra on$X$ it happens:
>
> $$\int_X f \, d(m_1 + m_2) = \int_X f \, dm_1 + \int_X f \, dm_2$$

I thought it is true for every measure. Because one can prove the risult for simple measurable and non negative functions. After that one can take $f$ to be non negative and take, thanks to simple aproximation theorem, a monotone sequence $s_n$ of simple measurable functions such that $s_n \rightarrow f$. Thus by monotone convergence theorem, and what above we have:

$$\int_X f \, d(m_1 + m_2) = \lim_n \int_X s_n \, d(m_1 + m_2) =\lim_n \left( \int_X s_n \, dm_1 + \int_X s_n \, dm_2 \right)$$

but by monotone convergence theorem

$$ \lim_n \int_X s_n\, dm_1 =  \int_X f \, dm_1$$
and
$$\lim_n \int_X s_n \,dm_2 =  \int_X f \, dm_2.$$

Thus the above limit is equal to the sum of the two. Thus the claim??

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning shows that $$\int f d(m_1+m_2) = \int f \, dm_1 + \int f dm_2$$ for any **non-negative** measurable function $f$. In order to extend this identity to functions taking values in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ you need some additional assumptions on the integrability of $f$ (e.g. $f \in L^1(m_1) \cap L^1(m_2)$ or something similar).

Comment: We have defined the integral for signed functions only when they are integrable. Anyway, since i have $|f| =f^+ + f^-$, it follows that $f$ is integrable respect $m1 +m2$ if and only if it is integrable with respect to $m1$ and $m2$. Thus i get the claim also for integrable functions, right?

Comment: @jJjjJ Yes, that's correct.